Create and save() methods of the ORM of Django not working and is blocked
I have an app created with docker, that use a container with django, a frontend with Vue.js and a database with Postgres.
The problem is, when I execute a query with create() or save(), it blocked the application and not create nothing. Nothing happen, only the app is blocked in the query and not advance. It not resolve any log.
It happens in Postman, CURL and frontend.
Logs of Postgres container resolve:

Unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction

I tried to configure the Firewall in localhost:8000, because I am using WSL, but it not resolve the problem.
My django configuration is with DATABASE_CONN_MAX_AGE=0.
I execute SHOW transaction_read_only; and it is OFF, and I can do Create queries from PGADMIN and it working correctly, so it create registers from PGAdmin, and I do not have any current connection that blocked the query.
I restart images, container, etc. And it happens anyway.
It happen in DEBUG true and Debug False.
It is my postgres container in docker-compose.yml.
services:
  django: &django
    container_name: iris2-backoffice
    build:
      context: ./iris2-backoffice/
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: iris_local_django
    depends_on:
      - minio
      - redis
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./iris2-backoffice/src:/app
      - oam_session_cache:/tmp/session
    env_file:
      - ./iris2-devtools/dotenv/backend/local/django
    command: run-devel
    ports: 
      - 8000:8000

postgres:
    image: postgres:10.1-alpine
    env_file:
      - ./iris2-devtools/dotenv/backend/local/postgres
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./postgres:/postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

I am trying to execute create and save queries in my django application with DDBB Postgres.
In addition: if I use cursor.execute it working correctly, so the problem is when execute the ORM of django with create and save.
      sql_query = """ INSERT INTO whatever (column, column, column, application_id, normalized_id, column,created_at, updated_at,enabled) VALUES (1, 1, NULL, NULL, 1, 1,'2024-05-10 15:06:28.692448+00','2024-05-10 15:06:28.692448+00',true) RETURNING id; """ 
        print(sql_query) 
        cursor.execute(sql_query)

